# Taking the limit of large scale in QFT integral

Tags: quantum-field-theory

I'm working with the massless Klein-Gordon field, so I have that:
$$\phi(x) = \frac{d^3\vec{p}}{(2\pi)^3} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 |\vec{p}|}} \bigg( a_p e^{-i p \cdot x} + a_p^\dagger e^{i p \cdot x} \bigg)_{p^0 = |\vec{p}|}$$
(Equation 2.47 in Peskin and Shroeder), and there is a definition of a 'smeared' version:
$$\tilde{\phi}_a (x) = \frac{1}{\pi^{3/2}a^3} \int d^3 \vec{y}\ \ \  \phi(y) e^{-|\vec{y}-\vec{x}|/a^2}$$
(from problem 1 of [this online QFT problemset](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-323-relativistic-quantum-field-theory-i-spring-2008/assignments/ft1ps03_08_1.pdf)) by taking a convolution with a gaussian. I've been trying to calculate the quantity:
$$\sigma^2 = \langle 0 | \tilde{\phi}_a^2 | 0 \rangle = \frac{1}{128\pi^9 a^6} \langle 0 | \bigg( \int d\vec{y}^3 \ \int d\vec{p}^3 \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 |\vec{p}|}} (a_p e^{-i p \cdot x} + a_p^\dagger e^{i p \cdot y}) e^{-|\vec{y}-\vec{x}|/a^2}\bigg)^2 |0 \rangle$$
$$=\frac{1}{128 \pi^9 a^6}\int d\vec{y}^3\  d\vec{z}^3\  d\vec{p}^3\  \frac{e^{i \vec{p} \cdot (\vec{z}-\vec{y})}}{p}  e^{-(|\vec{y}-\vec{x}|+|\vec{z}-\vec{x}|)/a^2}$$
where the last equality (possibly suspect?) was obtained by acting the creation operators on the vacuum states, and using orthogonality of $|p\rangle, |q\rangle$ for $p \neq q$. The problem set says to evaluate this in the limit of small $a$ and large $a$. For small $a$, the gaussian turns into a delta function, so it seems to be fine at first glance, but the resulting integral $\int 1/p d\vec{p}^3 $ doesn't converge; is this fine?

In the large $a$ limit, I have no idea what to do. I contemplated taylor expanding in $1/a$ but that doesn't seem to produce anything useful; and in any case I get infinities everywhere I go. I also thought to 'tame the infinities' by introducing another length scale $\Lambda$, performing the integral for distances on order $\Lambda$ or less and taking $\Lambda$ to infinity, but that doesn't really seem to help; doesn't $a$ already act like a length scale in this problem?